# Reaction of but-2-ene with Cl2/CCl4

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I have often studied the reaction of Br2/CCl4 with But-2-ene which results in formation of 
[image]

But I wondered what would be formed if Cl2/CCl4 reacts with But-2-ene. Does it lead to the formation of
This: [image]
Or This: [image]
Or something else which I never expected

Comment: What have you attempted to do with regards to the answer to this question? What makes you think it is something different?

Comment: Because although allylic halogenation reactions don't take place with Br2 direclty (NBS is usually used for the same for low concentration) I've seen allylic halogenation reactions taking place directly with Cl2 probably at a high temperature

Comment: And thats what made me wonder which course will this reaction take. Standard addition or allylic halogenation

Comment: High temperatures lead to radical reactions. $\ce{Cl2/CCl4}$ is a standard addition reaction leading to vicinal dihalides, no high temp here.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal Ok thanks got it. One more thing I noticed was that in allylic halogenation reactions of Cl2, at high temperatures ofcourse, it was in gaseous state and not dissolved.

Comment: $\ce{Cl2}$ becomes a gas at $\pu{-34.6 ^\circ C}$, what is expected at high temperatures?